# Definition of $\left(\infty, 1\right)$-category in context of homotopy type theory

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, type-theory, higher-category-theory, homotopy-type-theory

It has been proven that any locally presentable, locally cartesian closed $\left(\infty, 1\right)$-category models constructive dependent type theory (CDTT). From what I gather, this is supposed to *generalize* the fact that the category $\mathbf{sSet}$ of simplicial sets models CDTT.

But this confuses me. A common definition of an  $\left(\infty, 1\right)$-category is a simplicial set for which every inner horn has a filler. In what sense, then, can $\mathbf{sSet}$ be considered an $\left(\infty, 1\right)$-category?

My confusion may just be terminological, but any clarification would be appreciated!

Comment: It's a bit of a surprising question-have you never seen how to construct an $(\infty,1)$-category from a simplicially enriched category or a model category? $\mathbf{SSet}$ presents an $(\infty,1)$-category using, for instance, the Kan-Quillen model structure.

Comment: You should look up the "homotopy coherent nerve"

Comment: @KevinCarlson To clarify, an $\left(\infty, 1\right)$-category may be thought of as a simplicially enriched category in the context I asked about, correct? In this case, does an equivalence of $\left(\infty, 1\right)$-categories (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/equivalence+of+%28infinity%2C1%29-categories) refer to a Dwyer-Kan weak equivalence?

Comment: @KevinCarlson Moreover, as long as we use "simplicially enriched category" as our notion of an $\left(\infty, 1\right)$-category, do $\left(\infty,1\right)$-limits just refer to limits in the category of simplicially enriched categories in the ordinary sense?

Comment: The answers are yes, yes, and not at all. An $(\infty,1)$-limit is a limit inside a single $\infty$-category. In a fibrant simplicial category these can be computed as certain weighted enriched limits, but they’re more often discussed in terms of quasicategories.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Oops, what I meant to ask was whether an $\left(\infty, 1\right)$-limit coincides with an ordinary limit within a simplicially enriched category. You seem to say that this is, indeed, the case, correct?

Comment: @CuriousKid7 Not exactly. You have to be in a fibrant simplicially enriched category, so that all hom-simplicial sets are Kan complexes, and you can't just take an ordinary limit. If $F:J\to T$ is a diagram in a fibrant simplicially enriched category $T$ then the limit of $F$ *weighted by* the weight $j\mapsto N(J/j)$ models the $\infty$-categorical limit of $F$. This amounts to the equalizer of the two natural maps $\prod_{j\in J} F(j)^{N(J/j)}\to \prod_{j\to j'}F(j')^{N(J/j)}$, when $T$ is cotensored over simplicial sets.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Thank you. As a final clarification, does $N(J/j)$ here refer to the nerve of the over-category?

Comment: @CuriousKid7 Yes, that's right.